# Test Fails when running MSTest on commandline but passes in VS2012

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, mstest

I have one test out of a suite of tests that fails when running MSTest on the commandline. However, the same suite of tests passes within VS2012 IDE.

I verified that the same test project dll is being executed on both commandline and VS2012 IDE.

I verified this by commenting out a test method and observing MSTest report an updated test summary in which some other test failed which was passing before I commented out the test method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Are you using vstest.console.exe to run the tests from the command line?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. A test just happens to fail each time I run the test. I have not attempted vstest.console.exe.

Comment: Why is the test failing?  Either an error or failed assert, right?

Comment: vstest.console.tests worked for me. Post this as the answer and I will credit you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using VS 2012 or later, you should be using `vstest.console.exe` to run your tests.  Mstext.exe is left there for backward compatibility.  Using vstest.console.exe oftentimes fixes issues that only exist when run with mstest.exe.